# Record stream via JS

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

so i have my webRTC python server that streams audio and video to the browser via js in video and audio tag form

Now what can I do to record this stream on frontend I'm asking because i my current solution based solely on python and openCV it is to slow for modern era so Im re writing my whole project with different approach and now i'm stuck

**html**

```html
<a href="#"  id="start"  onclick="start()">Start</a>
<a href="#"  id="stop" onclick="stop()">Stop</a>

<div id="media">
    <audio id="audio" autoplay="true"></audio>
    <video id="video" autoplay="true" playsinline="true"></video>
</div>
```

**js**

```js
var pc = null;
var dc = null, dcInterval = null;

function createPeerConnection() {
    var config = {
        sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan'
    };

    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
    pc.addEventListener('track', function(evt) {
        if (evt.track.kind == 'video')
            document.getElementById('video').srcObject = evt.streams[0];
        else
            document.getElementById('audio').srcObject = evt.streams[0];
    });

    return pc;
}

function negotiate() {
    return pc.createOffer().then(function(offer) {
        return pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }).then(function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                resolve();
            } else {
                function checkState() {
                    if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                        pc.removeEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }
                pc.addEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        var offer = pc.localDescription;
        
        return fetch('/offer', {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                sdp: offer.sdp,
                type: offer.type,
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST'
        });
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(answer) {
        return pc.setRemoteDescription(answer);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        alert(e);
    });
}

function start() {
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';

    pc = createPeerConnection();

    var constraints = {
        audio: document.getElementById('use-audio').checked,
        video: false
    };

    if (document.getElementById('use-video').checked) {
        var resolution = document.getElementById('video-resolution').value;
        if (resolution) {
            resolution = resolution.split('x');
            constraints.video = {
                width: parseInt(resolution[0], 0),
                height: parseInt(resolution[1], 0)
            };
        } else {
            constraints.video = true;
        }
    }

    if (constraints.audio || constraints.video) {
        if (constraints.video) {
            document.getElementById('media').style.display = 'block';
        }
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
            stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                pc.addTrack(track, stream);
            });
            return negotiate();
        }, function(err) {
            alert('Could not acquire media: ' + err);
        });
    } else {
        negotiate();
    }

    document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'inline-block';
}

function stop() {
    document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'none';

    if (dc) {
        dc.close();
    }

    if (pc.getTransceivers) {
        pc.getTransceivers().forEach(function(transceiver) {
            if (transceiver.stop) {
                transceiver.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    pc.getSenders().forEach(function(sender) {
        sender.track.stop();
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        pc.close();
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Not sure of what you want exactly but this might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode

Comment: I'm streaming content to html and now I wanna start recording this stream onclick then save it